# Why prevent Name-mangling C files

Tags: c++, c, linker, name-mangling

Note: my question is for my knowledge im not trying to solve particular problem.

i was looking into using C library in CPP project to prevent compiler name mangling:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

1- but i also, read that C++ compiler will not mangle .c files. so why bother?

2- if you had a library of +500 c files. (headers + c files). how do you auto add this Extern "C" into them? is there a tool that automate this process?

Comment: I doubt you see this in header (.h) not implementation (.c).

Comment: @appleapple i think i saw them in both .c and .h files.

Comment: This doensn't address the question, but `extern "C"` says to mangle names **the same way the C compiler does**. C compilers typically add an underscore at the start of the name, although one that I used added an underscore at the other end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `c++` compiler may not do name mangling on `.c` files, but it definitely would mangle those included by `.cpp` files, so in header files it is needed
2. you can simply use `extern "C"{ file content here }`, this can be easily done in many tools.

---

I write a cmd script (.bat) for you

**WARNING** : this would overwrite existing files, make a backup!

```
@ECHO OFF
for /R %%f in (*.c,*.h) do (
   @echo extern "C" { > temp
   @echo. >> temp
   @type %%f >> temp
   @echo. >> temp   
   @echo } >> temp
   @type temp > %%f
   @echo processed %%f
)
```

Comment: hello, im going to flag it as answer, although are these tools ment for this specific problem or its text tool with somthing like plugin in Notepad++ or somthing like that? / or they come with IDE? i researched for them but couldnt find.

Comment: @Hasanalattar I mean some general tools. I write a cmd script (.bat) for you. (hope you're also using windows :)

Comment: @Hasanalattar: You can't find such a tool because there's generally no need for such a tool.

Comment: I don't think this simple wrapper script will work with something like `#include <math.h>`, which in C++ specifies some overloaded functions.

Comment: But apparently I'm wrong, since a quick test doesn't give me compiler errors. Interesting...

Comment: @aschepler it's because it probably have `extern "C++"` somewhere, which overwrite the `extern "C"`

Comment: @aschepler actually extern c just doesnt work on overloading fuctions

Comment: @aschepler since this is not OP's case, I'd like to keep my answer as-is, but it's a good point :)

Comment: @aschepler for completeness, [here is the document](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.link#4) for nested linkage specifications

Comment: @appleapple Yes, I do see there's at least one "`#ifdef __cplusplus extern "C++" {`" in my math.h, and some other compiler-specific tricks that may also be related.  It's nice they've made sure that sort of thing works, but I'm not certain of whether the C++ Standard actually says it needs to work.

Comment: @aschepler without the wrapper, the compiler still should be able to compile those `#includes`, I don't see why it would not work.

Answer (score 1):

"apple apple"'s answer is generally wrong.

A C++ compiler by definition compiles C++. Some compilers are C/C++ compilers, or support even more languages (GCC comes to mind). Those may use the file extension as a clue, but you generally can also pick one specific language. E.g. `gcc -x c++` picks the Gnu C++ compiler, even for .c files.

As for an existing C library, since you have the source files you do **not** need to prevent name mangling. Compile the library with the same compiler as your application. That causes the name mangling to be identical. No tools are needed.

I also suspect that you might think that `extern "C"` means "compile as C code". That's not the case. It means, "compile this C++ code so that its external interface is compatible with C". You still get all the C++ features on the inside.

Comment: for the first part, you mean that generally gcc will choose c compiler for .c files by default so it will not mangle them. even if they get included by cpp file ?
the second part was totally in my mind (i mean obviously why i should care that my compiler will mangle the c functions.. it knows what to do..) thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: I'm not sure it's quite fair to categorise apple's answer as "generally wrong", although I do agree that when they said "`c++` compiler may not..." they surely meant to say "your compiler (which is capable of building both C++ and C)" - other than that it's correct, no? OFC all of _your_ answer is otherwise right, but does skip over the important aspect of included headers used by code varyingly written in either language.

Answer (score 1):

[Additional answer]

Usually there's no need to edit the original file to add `extern "C"`. There's an easier alternative that leaves the file untouched:

```
// Foo.cpp
extern "C" {
   #include "Foo.c"
}
```

You tell your C++ compiler to compile Foo.cpp. It will first run the preprocessor, and that will insert Foo.c in the `extern "C" { }` block.